# Decentralized online shopping service

Tags: web-service, anonymity, p2p

Would it be possible to create an online shopping service like Amazon (or Silk Road) but also to make it decentralized so there would no main server users would have to trust with their data?

I imagine p2p approach could work here, although I have no idea how would you maintain integrity of distributed data...

Anyway, is it possible? If yes, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at distributed hash tables, magnet links and the bit-coin protocol.

I guess it is most certainly possible, but the complexity would easiely reach that of a larger rfc. too large to be discussed here.